# FCM Server side differentiate between iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, json, server, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notifications from my server (to a firebase token and not to a topic). I do not differentiate between the platforms, the server just sends the JSON via RestTemplate (Spring Boot App).

If I prepare it for Android, it works, but it does not for for iOS. But if I prepare it for iOS, it does not work for Android.

The case is: I want the notification and the background process (It should display the notification in any case foreground/background/killed and it should take key-value pairs from the data payload).

The problem is: If I use `notification` in my JSON, the notification would be displayed on iOS and on Android but just the iOS can handle the payload (in foreground/background/killed state). If I remove the `notification` tag in JSON, then everything works fine (Android and iOS receives the payload in all states, but the iOS does not display the notification).

In Android you can build the notification client side (like me), but in iOS its not possible.

So, how can I send a FCM (JSON) with a firebase-token and it is platform-independent? Both can handle it properly, both receive the payload and displays the message and payload should be handled in every state.

This works on android and displays the message (built client side) but does not work for iOS

```
{
   "content_available": true,
   "data":{
        "action":"bla",
        "value":"true",
        "id":"111111"
   },
   "android":{
      "priority":"high"
   },
   "apns":{
      "headers":{
         "apns-priority":"10"
      }
   },
   "to":"<MY_FCM_TOKEN>"
}
```

This displays the FCM for android and iOS, but handles the payload just on iOS

```
{
   "notification":{
      "sound":"default",
      "title":"Test Title",
      "body":"Message of FCM"
   },
   "content_available": true,
   "data":{
        "action":"bla",
        "value":"true",
        "id":"111111"
   },
   "android":{
      "priority":"high"
   },
   "apns":{
      "headers":{
         "apns-priority":"10"
      }
   },
   "to":"<MY_FCM_TOKEN>"
}
```

Or is it possible to declare the notification-tag just for iOS?
Or is it possible to create notifications also client side in iOS when a payload receives?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @VadimF. No, I dont found a solution

Answer (score 1):

Before sending a notification on the Server side I am checking whether the the platfomr is iOS or Android by using google's method:

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/IID_TOKEN
```

Which on success returns a JSON with a 'platform' parameter.
You can find more info [here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server)